# Using class extending asynctask to check internet connection in android activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, connection

By checking some questions on here I have managed to create the below class in order to check whether the user has an active internet connection. I want to use this in my android activities to check the connection before I load any data from the internet. I would like to ask if this is a suitable way of checking the user's internet connection and I would like someone to provide an example of how this would be called from within an activity (how to pass the context to it and how to obtain the `true/false` response back in my android activity.

```
public class ConnectionStatus  {
private Context context;

public ConnectionStatus(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context c) {
    NetworkInfo netInfo = null;
    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) c
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
public boolean CheckConnection() {
    if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection)
                    (new URL("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204")
                            .openConnection());
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            urlc.connect();
            return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 204 &&
                    urlc.getContentLength() == 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Error checking internet connection", e);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "No network available!");
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: I think a better design would be to put all of that functionality in a method of a non-AsyncTask class that would be called from all of the AsyncTasks in your Activities.  That way the code would be centralized and not replicated, and you would not have to use multiple AsyncTasks every time you want to do a network operation.

Comment: @DanielNugent that's pretty clever, didn't think of it. Can you just tell me how to pass the 'context` variable. What method do I have to call to obtain it in my activities

Answer (score 0):

I would get the network info outside the Async Task since it would be easier for you to handle how to react on the given network status.

For the Async Task, you could make it an inner class of your Activity, and check for the network status before calling the execute method of the Async Task.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

...
...
  private static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context c) {
    NetworkInfo netInfo = null;
    try {
      ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) c
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    // Something bad happen, better return false.
      return false;
    }
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
  }

//Let's assume you will call your data from the internet like this
  private void getDataFromTheInternet(){
  if (isNetworkAvailable){
     ConnectionStatus cStatus = new ConnectionStatus(getApplicationContext());
    cStatus.execute();
  }else{
  //Prevent the user that there is not a network connection
  }
}
```

Now, remove the isNetworkAvailable methof from the Asynk Task and there you go.

Additionally you could use a BroadCast receiver to check everytime the connection status changes so your application can react when it's offline or online following this [tutorial](http://easyandroidcookbook.blogspot.mx/2015/02/android-broadcast-receiver-getting.html)

Comment: I've read that the only way to trully check whether or not there is a working connection is to try to connect to a server and check for the response, as in in some cases this will pass, but the app will still crash attempting to connect as there may be an issue with the connection. I don't know how relevant that really is

Comment: You are missunderstanding the concepts of checking for a network. The case I added is to check if your application can access the internet. This means that you have a wifi connection or that there is a data network available and connected. Checking for a response on a specific URL will requiere to check the response or catch a TimeOut Exception

Comment: Basically I'm loading a bunch of data from my online server using Asynctasks to the app, I need to have the most reliable method to check the internet connection so that the app doesn't crash on the user during the loading of the Asynctask

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an Activity class that includes an AsyncTask, and shows how you could use your `ConnectionStatus` class in the updated version of your question.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        //Create Strings to pass to varargs of AsyncTask
        String s1 = "test1";
        String s2 = "test2";
        new MyAsync().execute(s1, s2);

    }

    class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        ConnectionStatus status;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String retVal = null;

            //Instantiate your object, use MainActivity.this for Context
            status = new ConnectionStatus(MainActivity.this);

            //capture varargs
            String sOne = params[0];
            String sTwo = params[1];

            boolean something = false;

            //Check network connectivity:
            if (status.CheckConnection()){

                //You have internet, do your network operations here
                //...............

                //Just here for an example:
                if (something == true){
                    retVal = sOne;
                }
                else{
                    retVal = sTwo;
                }

            }

            return retVal;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String arg) {
            //Update UI here, this runs on the Main UI thread of the Activity
            if (arg != null){
                textView.setText(arg);
            }
        }
    }

}
```